# how to sort data in a table that was pulled from database in php

Tags: php

I have a table which contains data pulled from a database. Now I want to sort the data column. I want to know how I can sort a column in PHP.

```
id, name, address, phonenumber....
1   dfdf   fsdfs   3434234
2   fff    rrrr    455345435
3   8ffdsf  erewr  454354
7    
100  ghgfh  trtre     454545
```

How can I sort on id when the id column is clicked in the table?

Comment: You need to add more info. Are you asking how to make a control that allows users to sort? Can you sort in the DB and merely display it in php?

Comment: By "table" do you mean an HTML table?  Do you have access to change the SQL query?  We need more info to be able to help.

Comment: That's better, but we still don't know if you are talking about sorting the HTML table, or the database table. And whether you have access to javascript, jquery, whatever tools you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your current MySQL query right now is something like:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`");
```

When echoing the results out to your users, you'll want to make the column headers in the table all links, that append a uri query containing what column to sort by, so for example, the `id` column header would echo out as: `<a href="index.php?sort=id">id</a>` and so on for the other columns. You should now change your query to something like:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` SORT BY ".$_GET['sort']." ASC");
```

Change the sort order to ASC/DESC depending on which direction you want it to be sorted.

Now when you echo out the data it should be sorted by whatever the `sort` value in the url is, so a url of `index.php?sort=name` will sort the results by name in whichever order you chose.

*(note that the mysql query should be cleansed to prevent from mysql injection)*